# Ignore emph in Theorem environment

Tags: theorems, emphasis

I'm using `enumitem` in a theorem environment:

```
\begin{theorem}
    The following are equivalent:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\emph{\roman*})]
        \item \label{ref1} Something.
        \item \label{ref2} Something else.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

The issue is that the roman numerals (i) and (ii) are not italicized. This is easily fixed by replacing `\emph{\roman*}` with `\roman*`, but then if I reference `ref1` or `ref2`, they will not be italicized. How can I get around this? (without italicizing the references by hand, which is arduous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*, ref=(\emph{\roman*})]
```